# SIMILAR TO function in postgresql is not working as expected

Tags: postgresql

I am using below code to do calculation

```
select column1 from tablename  where code  SIMILAR TO '%(-|_|–)EST[1-2][0-9](-|_)%'
```

for this column value -CSEST190-KCY18-04-01-L the condition was passed, but in  actual I want to ignore this type of data.
The correct value which should pass through the above condition is

```
-CS-EST19-0-KCY18-04-01-L
-CS_EST19-0-KCY18-04-01-L
```

Any suggestions, how to avoid this type of confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to go full-regex, instead of using SQL standard `SIMILAR TO`.

```
select column1 from tablename  where code ~ '[_–-]EST[12][0-9][_-]'
```

Notice this is does not have to match the full string, and you don't have to add `.*` on both ends (equivalent of `%` in `LIKE` and `SIMILAR TO`). The reason you got a match on that is, because of the underscore `_`, which is a single wildcard character.

Also, I switched the order, in the square brackets, so that the dash is the last character. That way it's treated as a character literal, not as a range specifier.

Comment: how to avoid _ underscore single wildcard character, any suggestion

Comment: You already have the `%` on both sides, but when converting to regular expression, you don't need it. If you want the equivalent of not having `%`, then start the pattern with `^` and end it with `$`. Calling `SIMILAR TO` and `LIKE` are both converted to regular expressions internally.

Comment: The equivalent of `%` is `.*`, but it's implied when it's on either left or right side of the string.

Comment: ya we will have more string on both sides...those were just sample